# Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, windows-services

I have a windows service which inserts data into some tables. It does so fine when in debug mode, but when I install it says "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." for every insert.

```
                        query = "INSERT INTO printers (" +
                            "hostname," +
                            "ip_address," +
                            "model," +
                            "picture_id," +
                            "connect_type," +
                            "status," +
                            "product_number," +
                            "Floor_ID," +
                            "print_corner," +
                            "serial_number," +
                            "printer_features" +
                            ") VALUES ('" +
                            exp.Devices[i].HostName.ToString() + "', '" +
                            exp.Devices[i].IpAddress.ToString() + "', '" +
                            exp.Devices[i].Model.ToString() + "', '" +
                            exp.Devices[i].PictureId.ToString() + "', '" +
                            exp.Devices[i].ConnectType.ToString() + "', '" +
                            exp.Devices[i].Status.ToString() + "', '" +
                            exp.Devices[i].ProductNumber.ToString() + "', '" +
                            exp.Devices[i].Floor.ToString() + "', '" +
                            exp.Devices[i].PrintCorner.ToString() + "', '" +
                            exp.Devices[i].SerialNumber.ToString() + "', '" +
                            exp.Devices[i].PrinterFeatures.ToString() +
                            "')";


        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + confParams.MpaSearchDatabase;

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(query);
                        myCommand.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                        insertedPrintersCount = insertedPrintersCount + 1;

                        Utils.Logger.Info("Device inserted: " + exp.Devices[i].HostName);
```

help!

Comment: The 'printers' tables are identical in both databases?

Comment: yeah, they are both copies of the exact same database, that's whats so weird about it

Answer (score 2):

The data type mismatch error indicates the query is expecting data of one type but you're providing another.  This query expression is passing every value as a `string` literal but several columns indicate they are likely a numerical value.  `ProductNumber` and `SerialNumber` for example.

In order to pass the values correctly (and prevent easy injection attacks) you'll want to use the `OleDbCommand` class to build up the call with values of the correct type.  Then let the underlying infrastructure translate it to the appropriate values.

Comment: As you suggest, there are some fields in the table that are actually of the "number" type. The thing is when I run the solution in debug mode it does the insert without problems, but with the service just recently I tried converting to integer those fields and had no luck. Why is it working in debug mode but gives me problems when I install it?